# ODI12c studio does not start in AIX7.2

Tags: database, oracle, etl

After installing odi12c, I run `./odi.sh`  in AIX 7.2. However, I have encountered the following error.

> 2021-06-14 16:11:07.651 ERROR Failed to boot IDE cleanly
> 2021-06-14 16:11:07.893 WARNING Not all children in Menu/ marked with the position attribute: [Tools], but some are: [View, Window]
> UIDefaults.getUI() failed: no ComponentUI class for: oracle.ide.controls.StatusBarControl$JDevStatusBar[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]

```
The following is the stack trace:

java.lang.Error
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUIError(UIDefaults.java:742)
at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.getUIError(MultiUIDefaults.java:141)
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:772)
at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1027)
at oracle.bali.ewt.statusBar.StatusBar.updateUI(StatusBar.java:480)
at oracle.bali.ewt.statusBar.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:104)
at oracle.ide.controls.StatusBarControl$JDevStatusBar.<init>(StatusBarControl.java:264)
at oracle.ide.controls.StatusBarControl.<init>(StatusBarControl.java:48)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbMainWindow$13.<init>(NbMainWindow.java:1098)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbMainWindow.createStatusBar(NbMainWindow.java:1098)
at oracle.ide.IdeMainWindow.getStatusBar(IdeMainWindow.java:622)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbMainWindow.getStatusBarStatic(NbMainWindow.java:228)
at com.oracle.jdeveloper.nbwindowsystem.NbStatusBar.getStatusLineElement(NbStatusBar.java:23)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow$7.run(MainWindow.java:426)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow.getStatusLineElements(MainWindow.java:438)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow.decoratePanel(MainWindow.java:392)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow.access$100(MainWindow.java:81)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.MainWindow$2.run(MainWindow.java:269)
at org.netbeans.core.windows.WindowManagerImpl$Exclusive$1.run(WindowManagerImpl.java:1563)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:322)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:769)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:108)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:704)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:739)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:216)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:127)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:112)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:104)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
```

Comment: This is a very generic error unlikely to get you an answer especially as this is probably not something used by a lot of people. Generic questions to ask yourself: Is it a clean install? On what OS? Is it a supported OS? Have you checked your filesystem for errors? Were there any? Did you reboot after install? Did you ask on the vendor support site? Did you try another version? Is there a VM or virtualized or AppImage version that you can try? Can you try another version of Java? Can you find a clean hard drive and try from clean install? Were there any installation messages you didn't read?

Comment: Also you can post links to what you installed and where you got it, to save anyone who might be able to help from having to search for it and possibly finding something different and wasting their time.

Answer (score 1):

AIX 7.2 does not support odi studio. You may go through the following combability matrix

https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/fusion-certification.html

You need to install ODI12c client in the windows PC and then connect with ODI server via ODI Studio.